# AJAX: failure when sending form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to send some form data to the backend using AJAX using the following code.

```html
<h1>Hotel Staff Timetabling</h1>

<form id="hotelinformation"><select name="info_hotelcode" class="hidden" ><option value="20250"  selected="selected">&nbsp;</option></select><select name="slotref" class="hidden" ><option value="377"  selected="selected">&nbsp;</option></select>
    <h3> Hotel Code: 20250</h3 ><h4> <h4>Max staff: <input  type="number" style="width: 50px;" id="info_number"  name="info_number" min="0" max="99" value="0"> </h4>
    <h5>Day: <select style="display:inline" id="info_day"  name="info_day">
      <option value="0"  selected="selected">Monday</option>
      <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="2">Wednesday</option><option value="3">Thursday</option>
      <option value="4">Friday</option></select>
     Time: <input  type="number" style="width: 40px;" id="info_hour"  name="info_hour" min="0" max="23" value="14"> </h5>
<button type="button" id="driver">Update</button>
<span id="spanner"></span>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>   
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#driver").click(function(event){
      var datastring =  $("#hotelinformation").serialize();
      console.log($("#hotelinformation").serialize());
       $.ajax( {
          type: "POST",
          url:'review/update.php',
          data: datastring,
          dataType: "json",
          success:function(data) {
             $('#spanner').append( "<strong>Successfully updated </strong>" );
             alert(data);
          },
          error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
          alert('Update failed. Exception:'+ exception);
        }
       });
    });
 });
</script>
```

I can see that the data

> info_hotelcode=20250&slotref=377&info_number=0&info_day=0&info_hour=14

is successfully sent. Nevertheless an exception triggers. The exception text **(edit: when correctly coded)** is

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

update.php contains code to handle the form data. I believe this to be correctly coded, but if it isn't, I know of no way to see the error messages generated by Apache.

The associated backend code is as follows

```
$data = array(
);


array_push($data, $_POST['info_hotelcode']);
array_push($data, $_POST['info_number']);



preparedValues($data, $dbh);


function preparedValues($values_data, $dbh)
{


    try{

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `module`
        (
        info_hotelcode,
        info_number
        )
        VALUES
        (
        :info_hotelcode,
        :info_number
        )
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        info_hotelcode = :info_hotelcode,
        info_number = :info_number
        ";

        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);


        $sth->bindValue(':info_hotelcode', $values_data[0]);
        $sth->bindValue(':info_number', $values_data[1]);

        $sth->execute();

    }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
        file_put_contents('PDOErrors2.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
        echo($e->getMessage());
        failure("Database connection failure (deleting data) -first pass ");
        }

}





echo json_encode(array('success' => 1));
$dbh = null;
```

The response body from the backend if not particularly interesting. Error reporting by the webserver is turned on, before anyone asks.

[image: network]

What can I do to try and debug this issue?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216268/discussion-on-question-by-stumbler-ajax-failure-when-sending-form-data).

Answer (score -1):

You showed the problem in your screenshot of Firefox debugger console. You told the jQuery ajax call to expect a JSON response but there is none. It's empty. This is what happens when you try and parse an empty string to JSON
[image]

Comment: OP's response is not JSON but it is also not empty. There's 6 bytes of something (probably whitespace) and their error refers to an unexpected character on line #2, not unexpected EOD

Comment: I consider whitespace "empty" and so does JSON.parse

Comment: Do you not see the difference between _"unexpected character"_ and _"unexpected end of data"_?

Answer (score -2):

It seems to be a backend error. 
Try replacing your alert in the error function with this in order to get more information.

```
alert(`Update failed. Status: ${jqxhr.status}, Message: ${jqxhr.statusText}`);
```

Comment: They're already getting the detailed error message, which says that the response isn't valid JSON. I don't think these properties will reveal anything useful, since it's not an HTTP error.

Comment: @Barmar Agree with you